# Change colour of buffers in openlayers

Tags: buffer, openlayers

I have the following JS code to create a 1 mile buffer in Openlayers using JSTS. However, I'd like to add 2 or 3 buffers but change the colour from the default for easier viewing.

So far, I've tried this as this styling as changed the fill/stroke of my points before

```
var source = new ol.source.Vector();
      fetch('http://18.207.139.64:8080/geoserver/egm715/wfs?service=WFS&' +
'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=egm715:Mid_Ulster1&' +
'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857').then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
        var features = format.readFeatures(json, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});

        var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();

        for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
          var feature = features[i];
          // convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
          var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());

          // create a buffer of 1 mile =1609 metres
          var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(1609);

          // convert back from JSTS and replace the geometry on the feature
          feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered));
        }

        source.addFeatures(features);
      });
      var buffer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        title: 'Mid Ulster Buffer - 1 mile',
        visible: false,
        style: new ol.style.Style(
    {
        image: new ol.style.Circle(
        {
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke(
            {
                color: [0, 102, 77],
                width: 2
            }
            ),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill(
            {
                color: [230, 255, 255, 0.6]
            }
            )
        }
    )
    }
    )
      });
```

However, the default colour remains - is there any way I can change it?

Comment: The image option in ol.style.Style is used to style point features with an icon or regular shapes such as a circle.. Your buffered geometry is a polygon, and is styled by stroke and fill options of ol.style.Style.

Comment: I've tried the following ```style: new ol.style.Style({stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: [0, 102, 77], width: 2}),fill: new ol.style.Fill( {color: [230, 255, 255, 0.6]})})``` with no luck either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mike indicated in his comment: "The image option in ol.style.Style is used to style point features with an icon or regular shapes such as a circle. Your buffered geometry is a polygon, and is styled by stroke and fill options of ol.style.Style"

Change the `style`:

```
style: new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Circle({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0, 102, 77],
      width: 2
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [230, 255, 255, 0.6]
    })
  })
})
```

To remove the `image: new ol.styld.Circle`, something like:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'blue',
      width: 3,
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)',
    }),
  }),
});
```

[image: screenshot of styled buffers]
**code snippet**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JSTS Integration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
  <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,TextDecoder"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jsts@2.3.0/dist/jsts.min.js"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>
    var json = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.1",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-760868.77651775, 7266893.59283424]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.2",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-745762.5639359, 7273034.00676835]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.3",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-746154.82706286, 7273335.72201827]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.4",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-744607.30629421, 7255093.16775183]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.5",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-745202.69041239, 7255413.35399374]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.6",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-753889.58828371, 7266121.43420011]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.7",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-753078.05077876, 7267405.03419487]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.8",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-797828.64640079, 7249092.54222032]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.9",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-753881.35356931, 7266025.39133859]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.10",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-742327.05477715, 7302434.75328766]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.11",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750757.26468702, 7294103.95069428]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.12",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-742442.85453496, 7302225.99299248]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.13",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750678.90941561, 7293250.62728349]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.14",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-751029.88000637, 7293128.14558216]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.15",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750678.90941561, 7293250.62728349]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.16",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750757.26468702, 7294103.95069428]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.17",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-743083.01564625, 7280176.20812626]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.18",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750837.75665786, 7294119.26420537]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.19",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750757.26468702, 7294103.95069428]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.20",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-750790.13706862, 7294411.61511293]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.21",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-751029.88000637, 7293128.14558216]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.22",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-729059.04788702, 7288230.5536544]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "FoodOutlets-MidUlst1.23",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [-771157.83824017, 7283468.51757007]
        },
        "geometry_name": "the_geom",
        "properties": {}
      }, ],
      "totalFeatures": 140,
      "numberMatched": 140,
      "numberReturned": 140,
      "timeStamp": "2021-03-02T05:15:46.157Z",
      "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
      }
    };

    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var features = format.readFeatures(json, {
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });

    var source = new ol.source.Vector(); // VectorSource();
    var parser = new jsts.io.OL3Parser();
    parser.inject(
      ol.geom.Point,
      ol.geom.LineString,
      ol.geom.LinearRing,
      ol.geom.Polygon,
      ol.geom.MultiPoint,
      ol.geom.MultiLineString,
      ol.geom.MultiPolygon
    );

    for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      var feature = features[i];
      // convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
      var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());

      // create a buffer of 1 mile =1609 metres adjusted for the projection
      var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(1609 / ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, ol.extent.getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent())));
      // create a buffer of 40 meters around each line
      // var buffered = jstsGeom.buffer(1000);

      // convert back from JSTS and replace the geometry on the feature
      feature.setGeometry(parser.write(buffered));
    }

    source.addFeatures(features);

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
      source: source,
      style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: 'blue',
          width: 3,
        }),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3)',
        }),
      }),
    });

    var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
      target: document.getElementById('map'),
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([126.979293, 37.528787]),
        zoom: 15,
      }),
    });
    map.getView().fit(source.getExtent());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1609 EPSG:3857 projection units is not 1 mile in that region, but that is a separate issue!

Comment: @Mike Oh really? I wasn't aware of this. Is EPSG:3857 a flat surface representation?

Comment: @user_map123 like any flat representation of a curved surface it distorts as you move away the projection's latitude or longitude of true scale (in this case that is the equator, the poles being infinite and unreachable, so anywhere away from the equator a 1609 "meter" buffer will be less than 1 mile on the ground).  When buffering you can use the point resolution at the center of the geometry extent `1609 / ol.proj.getPointResolution('EPSG:3857', 1, ol.extent.getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()))` to adjust to the true scale at that point.

Comment: @Mike, thanks for that . Updated the example per your comment